# How to isolate duplicate subvalues of a group by SQL statement

Tags: php, sql, mysql, percona

I have been tasked with trying to format and display data via PHP and SQL from a CSV spreadsheet to get rid of duplicate and incorrect values.  I already have the code written that imports the CSV to the database without any issues, but my problem is trying to figure out how to write a query to do what I need as the GROUP BY is not working for my needs.

My database server type is Percona Server.

Query I have tried, and is to the extent of my knowledge of SQL for grouping data:

```
SELECT ourso,sodte,invnr,indat,itnsa,cusnr,txam1,txcd1,txbod,state,invam,itnbr,itdsc,bzip,szip 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY ourso,sodte,invnr,indat,itnsa,cusnr,txam1,txcd1,txbod,state,invam,itnbr,itdsc,bzip,szip
```

Sample Data (What my table columns look like with some sample data)

| id | ourso | sodte | invnr | indat | comno | shpnr | city | itnsa | linam | extca | cusnr | txam1 | bcity | txcd1 | txbod | state | invam | itnbr | itdsc | bzip | szip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0TYXA | 2020-01-08 | 762819 | 2020-01-12 | 1 | 0 | CHARLOTTE | 8075.48 | 8075.48 | 6957.90 | 622000 | 0.00 | CHARLOTTE | 1 | NC0060 | NC | 2740.59 | IT-1923 | ITEM INFO | 28208 | 28208 |
| 2 | 0TYXA | 2020-01-08 | 762819 | 2020-01-12 | 1 | 0 | CHARLOTTE | 8075.48 | 8075.48 | 6957.90 | 622000 | 0.00 | CHARLOTTE | 1 | NC0060 | NC | 10021.21 | IT-1920 | ITEM INFO | 28208 | 28208 |
| 3 | 0TYXA | 2020-01-08 | 762819 | 2020-01-12 | 1 | 0 | CHARLOTTE | 1149.98 | 1149.98 | 996.79 | 622000 | 0.00 | CHARLOTTE | 1 | NC0060 | NC | 10021.21 | IT-1923 | ITEM INFO | 28208 | 28208 |
| 4 | 0TYXA | 2020-01-08 | 762819 | 2020-01-12 | 1 | 0 | CHARLOTTE | 1149.98 | 1149.98 | 996.79 | 622000 | 0.00 | CHARLOTTE | 1 | NC0060 | NC | 10021.21 | IT-1920 | ITEM INFO | 28208 | 28208 |

In the sample above, I have 4 rows, but the itnsa/linam/extca columns are being duplicated.  the values for id 1 and 4 are correct for their respective column "itnbr", but 2 and 3 are displaying values for the wrong items.

Is there a way to write a SELECT statement that will group together same "invnr" rows, but make the itnsa/linam/extca only show the correct value?

The spreadsheet is over 60,000 rows with these errors throughout the entire spreadsheet because of how it exported (we have no control over this), and have switched to new software, but this data is from the old software.

Any recommendations would be welcome, as I have not been able to find an answer via google (I have also explored the use of DISTINCT, but it is not working in how I understand to use it).

Comment: "...but 2 and 3 are displaying values for the wrong items" -- How can you tell which ones are the good ones and which one are the bad ones?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Percona can use MySQL, MongoDB, etc.

Comment: I'm using PHPMyAdmin and mysqli to connect to database via PHP.

As far as how I am verifying what values are correct, I am having to crossreference them in the old software that the data was exported from to verify what value goes to what.

Comment: Since you're grouping by all the columns, you'll get a separate row if any column is different.

Comment: If you want to combine rows, you should just group by the columns that need to be unique, and use aggregation functions like `SUM()` for the columns that should be comined.

Comment: If you are crossreferencing it with external data to decide which rows are good or bad, a single query internal to this database won't be able to filter out the bad ones. Maybe you could store the "good IDs" in a separate table, so that info is available for the query.

Comment: Hmm.  Let me take a look into aggregation.  I may wind up having to (with much reluctance) have to manually edit / delete each row of the original spreadsheet to remove duplicates and insure each is displaying the correct values before importing to the database.

Comment: if there are just 60000 rows, consider just doing the work you need done in php and don't even put the data in the database?